# string dump of models appearing in views in Rails 4.2.1

Tags: erb, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have three Rails projects on 4.2.1 and at the bottom of all my views where the .erb is operating on a model, it dumps it out a string of the model into my view.  It's really annoying me and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.  Anybody else seen this or know what's up?

I've double/triple checked, I'm an not adding any <%= model.inspect %> anywhere in my view.  I am passing the model down through partials, but doubt that has anything to do with it...  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: show us your `layout.html.erb` or the layout view that's causing the issue. Also, is it possible that are you accidentally  adding `<%=` to iterations: `<%= @foo.each...` vs `<% @foo.each ...`?

Comment: Ahhh, yes.  Dimitry, thank you sir!   You're right, I had accidentally used <%= @properties.in_groups_of(4) do |row| %>   :\   Thank you.